# windows command line and Python

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I have a python script that i want to run from the command line but unsure how to run it. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you installed Python on your PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python myscript.py`

Answer (score 4):

I do it this way:

```
C:\path\to\folder> yourscript.py
```

Comment: This works great if you have the Python interpreter as the default program to open .py files.

Comment: isn't it what installer does by default?

Comment: @SilentGhost: the user may want to open Python files in an editor by default.

Comment: Executing the script is default behaviour for .js and .vbs files as well on Windows, so it's at least following the convention ;)

Answer (score 3):

See [Basic Hints for Windows Command Line Programming](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/command_line.shtml#path).

If your python installation directory is included in `%PATH%` -

```
C:\> python myscript.py
```

If you know the installation path:

```
C:\> C:\python26\python myscript.py
```

And, you can insert a `hashbang` in the 1st line of the script:

```
#! C:\python26\python
```

and it will run by typing just the script name. This is the content of `p.py`:

```
#!C:\python26\python
import sys
print sys.path
```

And calling it directly from a `cmd.exe` window:

```
C:\>p.py
['C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python26.zip', 'C:\\Python26\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python26\\lib', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Python26', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python26\\lib]
```

Comment: Oops, deleted my comment. I was asking what Johannes answered. SilentGhost's answer makes gimel's hashbang variant work, I guess, though it does work because of the extension and not because of the hashbang.

Comment: Works on my windows installation of python2.6.

Answer (score 2):

If your script is foo.py, you can simply do

```
C:\Python25\python.exe foo.py
```

Assuming you have python 2.5 installed in the default location. Alternatively, you can add C:\Python25 to your %PATH%, so that:

```
python foo.py
```

will work. But be aware that changing %PATH% may affect applications (that's why it is not done by the python installer by default).

Answer (score 1):

You might find it useful to include a .bat file which calls the .py script. Then all you need to do is to type the name of your script to run it.

Try something like:
python %~dp0\%~n0.py %*

(From http://wiki.tcl.tk/2455)

Comment: This has the added benefit that you can let users double-click the .bat file. Sadly, it still depends on python being part of %PATH%.

Answer (score 0):

1. do you have python installed? if not
   install it from python.org
2. on command line use

   python "path to
       script.py"
3. if python is not in PATH
       list you can add it to PATH in
       environment variables or directly
       use path to python.exe e.g.

   ```
       c:\python25\python.exe myscript.py
   ```